# Variable as command; eval vs bash -c

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-script

I was reading a bash script someone made and I noticed that the author doesn't use eval to evaluate a variable as a command
The author used

```
bash -c "$1"
```

instead of

```
eval "$1"
```

I assume using eval is the preferred method and it's probably faster anyway. Is that true?
Is there any practical difference between the two? What are notable differences between the two?

Comment: In some occasions, you can get away without either. `e='echo foo'; $e` works just fine.

Answer (score 47):

`eval "$1"` executes the command in the current script. It can set and use shell variables from the current script, set environment variables for the current script, set and use functions from the current script, set the current directory, umask, limits and other attributes for the current script, and so on. `bash -c "$1"` executes the command in a completely separate script, which inherits environment variables, file descriptors and other process environment (but does not transmit any change back) but does not inherit internal shell settings (shell variables, functions, options, traps, etc.).

There is another way, `(eval "$1")`, which executes the command in a subshell: it inherits everything from the calling script but does not transmit any change back.

For example, assuming that the variable `dir` isn't exported and `$1` is `cd "$foo"; ls`, then:

- `cd /starting/directory; foo=/somewhere/else; eval "$1"; pwd` lists the content of `/somewhere/else` and prints `/somewhere/else`.
- `cd /starting/directory; foo=/somewhere/else; (eval "$1"); pwd` lists the content of `/somewhere/else` and prints `/starting/directory`.
- `cd /starting/directory; foo=/somewhere/else; bash -c "$1"; pwd` lists the content of `/starting/directory` (because `cd ""` doesn't change the current directory) and prints `/starting/directory`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about (eval "$1"), is it any different from source?

Comment: @whoami `(eval "$1")` has nothing to do with `source`. It's just a combination of `(…)` and `eval`. `source foo` is roughly equivalent to `eval "$(cat foo)"`.

Comment: We must have been writing our answers at the same time...

Comment: @whoami The primary difference between `eval` and `.dot` is that `eval` works with *arguments* and `.dot` works with *files.*

Comment: Thanks both of you. My previous comment appears to be kinda stupid now that I read it again...

Comment: by `bash "$1"`, did you mean `bash -c "$1"`?

Answer (score 27):

The most important difference between

```
bash -c "$1"
```

And

```
eval "$1"
```

Is that the former runs in a subshell and the latter does not. So:

```
set -- 'var=something' 
bash -c "$1"
echo "$var"
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
#there doesn't seem to be anything here
```

```
set -- 'var=something' 
eval "$1"
echo "$var"
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
something
```

I have no idea why anyone would ever use the executable `bash` in that way, though. If you must invoke it, use the POSIX guaranteed built-in `sh`. Or `(subshell eval)` if you wish to protect your environment.

Personally, I prefer the shell's `.dot` above all.

```
printf 'var=something%d ; echo "$var"\n' `seq 1 5` | . /dev/fd/0
```

#### OUTPUT

```
something1
something2
something3
something4
something5
```

#### BUT DO YOU NEED IT AT ALL?

The only cause to use either, really, is in the event that your variable actually assigns or evaluates another, or word-splitting is important to the output.

For instance:

```
var='echo this is var' ; $var
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
this is var
```

That works, but only because `echo` doesn't care about its argument count.

```
var='echo "this is var"' ; $var
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
"this is var"
```

See? The double-quotes come along because the result of the shell's expansion of `$var` is not evaluated for `quote-removal`.

```
var='printf %s\\n "this is var"' ; $var
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
"this
is
var"
```

But with `eval` or `sh`:

```
    var='echo "this is var"' ; eval "$var" ; sh -c "$var"
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
this is var
this is var
```

When we use `eval` or `sh` the shell takes a second pass at the results of the expansions and evaluates them as a potential command as well, and so the quotes make a difference.  You can also do:

```
. <<VAR /dev/fd/0
    ${var:=echo "this is var"}
#END
VAR
```

#### OUTPUT

```
this is var
```

Answer (score 5):

I did a quick test:

```
time bash -c 'for i in {1..10000}; do bash -c "/bin/echo hi"; done'
time bash -c 'for i in {1..10000}; eval "/bin/echo hi"; done'
```

(Yes, I know, I used bash -c to execute the loop but that should not make a difference).

The results:

```
eval    : 1.17s
bash -c : 7.15s
```

So `eval` is faster. From the man page of `eval`:

> The eval utility shall construct a command by concatenating arguments together, separating each with a   character. The constructed command shall be read and executed by the shell.

`bash -c` of course, executes the command in a bash shell. One note: I used `/bin/echo` because `echo` is a shell built-in with `bash`, meaning a new process does not need to be started. Replacing `/bin/echo` with `echo` for the `bash -c` test, it took `1.28s`. That is about the same. Hovever, `eval` is faster for running executables. The key difference here is that `eval` does not start a new shell (it executes the command in the current one) whereas `bash -c` starts a new shell, then executes the command in the new shell. Starting a new shell takes time, and that is why `bash -c` is slower than `eval`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to compare `bash -c` with `eval` not `exec`.

Comment: @JosephR. Oops! I'll change that.

Comment: @JosephR. It should be fixed now. Also I redid the tests a bit more and `bash -c` isn't *that* bad...

Comment: While this is true, it misses the fundamental difference that the command is executed in different environments. It's obvious that starting a new instance of bash will be slower, this is not an interesting observation.